# Plugin para criar construtor de instância da variável em tempo de execução

Tags: java, junit, kotlin, intellij, real-time

Preciso criar alguns testes utilizando variáveis já instanciadas em tempo de execução, e invés de montar manualmente, objeto por objeto, atributo por atributo, gostaria de alguma ferramenta que automatiza-se isso e já trouxesse o código com os objetos e variáveis preenchidas, essa ferramenta existe no Intellij?

Por exemplo, apenas arrastando a variável do Watch para o código, gostaria que já trouxesse os objetos valorizados. São muitos objetos e atributos que tem que preencher, ocasionando uma perda de tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer uma ferramenta dentro do Intellij IDEA que preencha com valores aleatórios uma classe qualquer no meio do debug do código?

Answer (score 0):

> Por exemplo, apenas arrastando a variável do Watch para o código, gostaria que já trouxesse os objetos valorizados

O Intellij IDEA em si não fornece um recurso assim, e ao meu ver não faria muito sentido para o seu teste unitário, dado o início da sua pergunta:

> Preciso criar alguns testes utilizando variáveis já instanciadas em
>   tempo de execução, e invés de montar manualmente, objeto por objeto,
>   atributo por atributo, gostaria de alguma ferramenta que automatiza-se
>   isso e já trouxesse o código com os objetos e variáveis preenchidas

Pelo que entendo, você precisa na verdade de uma ferramenta no seu teste unitário para preencher classes com valores aleatórios, para que não precise ficar populando manualmente cada um.

Uma biblioteca que pode te ajudar é o [PODAM](http://mtedone.github.io/podam/):

```
// Simplest scenario. Will delegate to Podam all decisions
PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();

// This will use constructor with minimum arguments and
// then setters to populate POJO
Pojo myPojo = factory.manufacturePojo(Pojo.class);

// This will use constructor with maximum arguments and
// then setters to populate POJO
Pojo myPojo2 = factory.manufacturePojoWithFullData(Pojo.class);

// If object instance is already available,
// Podam can fill it with random data
Pojo myPojo3 = MyFactory.getPojoInstance();
factory.populatePojo(myPojo3);
```

Existem [outras](https://github.com/benas/random-beans) também. Mas a ideia é resolver este problema antes da execução do seu teste unitário.